# Migrating Java and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, java-9, spring-boot-starter

Trying to upgrade the versions of Java and SpringBoot.

While Updating SpringBoot Starter parent version as 2.1.1.Release from 1.5.5 getting this below Error when trying to build the project Maven clean install

incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType on SpringApplicationBuilder

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ABC.class).web(true).run(args);
    }
```

Comment: That's incomplete information. When do you get this error? What code does it pertain to? Please share a MCVE.

Comment: If it is compile time error check your build path.

Comment: @nullpointer- Getting this error while build the project

Comment: Simple - you need to use `WebApplocationType.SERVLET` instead of `true`. Although I would suggest just removing that altogether as it's unnecessary. Just use `SpringApplication.run(ABC.class. args)`.

Comment: Also - `ABC.class` is not in PascalCase. Please stick to Java naming conventions.